# QTableView header menu position

Tags: python, menu, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I'm developing a GUI using PyQt5 under Python3. I'm trying to add menus to the column headers of a rather wide QTableView (wider than my screen => this is fine!).

My code positions these menus with their respective column headers, as desired, for the initial columns. However, when I use the scrollbar on the QTableView widget's bottom to scroll sideways, the position of the menus is off (basically, Qt places each menu where the corresponding column would be without scrolling).

How can I make the menu-position aware of the side-scrolling, so the menus get shown in the right place for all columns?

Here's a working mini-example (the relevant part is the `on_header_sectionClicked` method).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from PyQt5 import QtSql
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QTableView, QApplication, 
                             QAbstractItemView, QHeaderView, QMenu,
                             QAction)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
import sys

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300, 150)

        self.createConnection()
        self.fillTable()
        self.createModel()
        self.initUI()

    def createConnection(self):
        self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("test.db")
        if not self.db.open():
            print("Cannot establish a database connection")
            return False

    def fillTable(self):
        self.db.transaction()
        q = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        q.exec_("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars;")
        q.exec_("""CREATE TABLE Cars (Company TEXT, Model TEXT, Year_bought INT, Month_bought INT, Day_bought INT, 
        Owner_surname Text, Owner_firstname, Color TEXT)""") 
        q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('Honda', 'Civic', 2009, 2, 12,'Meyers', 'Peter', 'sunflower-yellow')") 
        q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('Volkswagen', 'Beetle Cabriolet', 2013, 10, 30, 'Heffernon', 'Jeremiah', 'skyblue')")
        self.db.commit()

    def createModel(self):
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
        q = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        query = "select * from cars"
        q.exec_(query)
        self.model.setQuery(q)

    def initUI(self):
        self.view = QTableView()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.header = self.view.horizontalHeader()
        self.header.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.header.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_header_sectionClicked)
        mode = QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection
        self.view.setSelectionMode(mode)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view) 

    def on_header_sectionClicked(self, index):
        self.col_index = index
        menu = QMenu(self)
        action1 = QAction("Filter me", self)
        action1.triggered.connect(self.on_menu_clicked)  
        menu.addAction(action1)

        #FIXME: position the menu correctly
        headerPos = self.view.mapToGlobal(self.header.pos())        
        posY = headerPos.y() + self.header.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.header.sectionPosition(self.col_index)
        menu.exec_(QPoint(posX, posY))

    def on_menu_clicked(self):
        print("Filtering column {}!".format(self.col_index))

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        if (self.db.open()):
            self.db.close()


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Edit**:

To clarify: as the menus will actually be filter-menus, I would prefer to not position them using the cursor but have the menu-position anchored to the column, to provide a "dropdown"-like interface like in the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works correctly if [sectionViewportPosition](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sectionViewportPosition) is used:

```
def on_header_sectionClicked(self, index):
    ...
    #FIXME: position the menu correctly
    headerPos = self.view.mapToGlobal(self.header.pos())        
    posY = headerPos.y() + self.header.height()
    posX = headerPos.x() + self.header.sectionViewportPosition(self.col_index)        
    menu.exec_(QPoint(posX, posY))
```